# Get limit records from SharePoint List into SSRS 2008 R2

Tags: list, sharepoint-2010, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am trying to get specific data from Sharepoint 2010 List into SQL Server 2008 R2 Reporting Service , i am using the Data Source as SharePoint List , then i set the Data set using Query builder after that i got this code :

```
<RSSharePointList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ListName>Minstry of Labor</ListName>
  <ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name="Title" />
    <FieldRef Name="Employee_x0020_No_x002e_" />
    <FieldRef Name="Non_x002d_Employee_x0020_No_x002e" />
    <FieldRef Name="Total" />
    <FieldRef Name="Entry_x0020_Date" />
    <FieldRef Name="Employee_x0020_No_x0020__x0025_" />
    <FieldRef Name="ID" />
  </ViewFields>
</RSSharePointList>
```

this Query will return all data from the list , i want just to get the last record ,not all records ,how can i do that , thank you